# variable explorer within spyder (python) missing

Tags: python, variables, explorer, spyder

I'm using Python 2.7.10 with Spyder 2.3.5.2 but I've seemed to have closed the window which shows all the variables (variable explorer) and their values. How can I re-open this again so that I can see all the values/arrays within my script etc.?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Top bar try to navigate to the following:

```
View->
Panes->
Variable Explorer -> Check it
```

[image]